# Setting cocos2d-x for macosx and windows7

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, multiplatform

We are using cocos2d-x in a school project and in our group there are mac users and windows users. We setup cocos2d-x as it is multiplatform. Currently, we have directories as;

```
Classes
cocos2d
proj.ios_mac
proj.win10
proj.win32
Resources
..
```

Mac users created the initial files and everything saved under the Classes folder as it is supposed to be. I mean this is the way to have a shared codebase between different projects with cocos2d-x.

The problem here is the created files and subfolders don't appear in the visual studio project. When we tried to add them manually, we got many errors because the visual studio doesn't create folders, it creates filters instead. (and also adding these files manually every time isn't really good)

We are kind of newbies on this area, can you please explain how to set up the project properly, so we can work on it with both Xcode and VisualStudio.

What should we do to sync everything automatically without having any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you generated the project through the Python script? [Script](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game)

I have worked only with Windows platform and I understand that the Windows project is the folder "proj.win32" and the Mac is "proj.ios_mac", and generates a project with two default classes and their respective headers (HelloWorld and AppDelegate) , Located in the folder "Classes" and in "Resources" you can create subfolders with all kinds of resources of the game. I do not understand when you say "create subfolders and files and they do not appear in Visual Studio".

Does each person work on their Mac computer and their Windows computer respectively?

[Is it possible that you are referring to this?](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/adding-new-class-file-using-visual-studio-2012-cocos2d-x/17355)